# I have date in string i want to convert it into date format but i got an error

Tags: java, string, date

```
String stringDate="2014-03-20T17:59:03+07:00";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
Date startDate = df.parse(stringDate);
```

But I got an error that java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2014-03-20T17:59:03+07:00"

Comment: You realize that the format you provide to the simple date formatter should match the format of the date you're attempting to parse?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Format Wrong:**

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

[here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

**Edit :**

```
String stringDate="2014-03-20T17:59:03+07:00";//2014-03-20T17:59:03+07:00 2014-03-20T17:59:03-07:00 
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            Date startDate = sdf.parse(stringDate);
            System.out.println(startDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: [java.text.ParseException] **: Unparseable date: "2014-03-20T10:59:03Z"**

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the format you are asking for df to parse, and the one you are giving it. stringDate is formatted as "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:33+ss:ss", but df expects "dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss". To fix this either change the format of your input or the format of df.

Answer (score 0):

The format string for parsing you're looking for is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`, however `Z` expects a format of `+0700` for the time zone, instead of `+07:00`, so you need to do some string replacement first, to get rid of the colon.

```
String stringDate = "2014-03-20T17:59:03+07:00";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
Date startDate = df.parse(stringDate.replaceAll("([+-]\\d{2}):(\\d{2})$", "$1$2"));
System.out.println(startDate); // output "Thu Mar 20 11:59:03 CET 2014" in my time zone
```

Answer (score 0):

The Joda-Time library accepts these ISO 8601 strings directly, parsed with a built-in formatter.

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "2014-03-20T17:59:03+07:00" );
```

If you really need a java.util.Date object (best to avoid j.u.Date when you can), convert.

```
java.util.Date date = dateTime.toDate();
```